# Why is the supercritical fluid region a perfect rectangle?

Tags: pressure, temperature, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, phase-diagram

The melting, sublimation and evaporation curves are all non straight lines in a (p,T) phase diagram, while the curves that divide liquid/gas regions from supercritical fluid region are perfectly straight. Is this the result of approximations or is it a separate special phenomenon?

Comment: Just as a default observation: it's surely partly just the luck of the choice of coordinates. But, yes, equally surely, that "luck" reflects some physical principle. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the usual chart as presented should be as interpreted as "boundless" in both the upward and rightward direction -- although at some point the atoms in the fluid will ionize into a plasma.  While it's not usually shown, it's still a phase transition.